# To execute make command for different files from vim editor

Tags: c, linux, vim, makefile, vi

I have two different independent files opened in vim editor with buffers `b1` pointing to `abc.c` and `b2` pointing to `xyz.c`.

Each of them are in different folders and are having different Makefiles.

Is it possible to execute `make` command in both the buffers for their respective files?

Currently If I open `abc.c` from its respective folder, then I can only execute `make` command for that file (`abc.c`).If the same command is executed in `b2` (`xyz.c`),makefile for `abc.c` is getting compiled.

How should I modify to execute `make` command of `xyz.c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to `:set autochdir` (or one one of the other options: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file) so that `:make` will run in the same directory as the source file.